# Funding with PHD +MS admission

Tags: phd, graduate-school, graduate-admissions, application, funding

I have completed my BSc in physics  and now doing my MS in my country(Bangladesh), but I want to do PHD/PHD+MS in USA with decent funding (RA or TA).
I know In a PHD level, funding may be available, but what about MS?
I'm saying this because I want to apply in this fall-2014 and during application I may not get my MS results .

Comment: If you're already in an MS program now, you're probably not even _eligible to apply_ to an MS program in the US, at least in the same field.  Just go for the PhD.

Comment: But I have not finished  the course yet and during the application, I will not be able to show my MS results. Will they accept me in  a PHD program without MS?

Comment: Yes, of course.  Most people apply to degree N+1 while they are still working on degree N.

Comment: And, at least in the sciences in the US, earning the MS is not required, and many do not do it. I applied to a PhD program while I was finishing my BS. I never earned the MS. Don't worry that your MS is not complete! Just go for the PhD!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In most cases, you do not have to be a MS *graduate* in order to apply for a PhD. I was a MS *candidate* when I applied for PhD about 4 years ago. I could only show 2 semesters worth of results from my MS program. It works.

Also, in *most* programs around the HCI/information science space (and if I might venture to propose, also in computer science), there is very *limited* funding for MS only programs. Things might be different in physics. I will leave it to the folks who know physics better to comment.

Answer (score 2):

In the US, you can apply to PhD programs without having a master's degree; this is actually the case in many fields. However, you will have to successfully complete the requirements for candidacy to a PhD program before being admitted to the doctoral phase of the program.

Funding for PhD-level programs at reputable departments (at least in science and engineering) should normally be guaranteed for some fixed term, provided you are making adequate progress and satisfy all program requirements. (What you have to do for such funding—whether it be research or TA—may vary, but that the funding will come from somewhere should be stated in advance.)

Answer (score 0):

Whether a US university would accept you into a PhD program would depend on the University itself - you'll need to contact them and ask them directly.

Having said that, do you have semester results in your MS, in your application you could state these and say that the final results are pending.  Ask the universities you apply to if it is alright to submit your final transcript a little bit later.

In the meantime, gather all your academic credentials that may help in your application - published papers, conference presentations (if any), references etc